# WMP Skipping Chapters When Restored to Fullscreen

Tags: windows-media-player

I just noticed a rather interesting issue with WMP. I'm watching a DVD while working, and noticed that if I minimize it to my taskbar, and open up the small preview window I can watch it just fine. But if I restore it while it's playing, it immediately skips ahead to the next chapter, blowing right past several minutes of content.

Is this standard behavior? Is there a work-around to keep it from doing this?

Comment: WMP version? OS?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall it by downloading it here

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/11/default.aspx